# I want my drawer header to overlap stack navigator header but i am unable to do so

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want drawer header to overlay stack header 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O48a2.png)

but my currently drawer header is coming below the stack header [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdxN6.png)

What could be the problem

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have your DrawerNavigator inside a StackNavigator like so

```
const stack = StackNavigator({
  DrawerStack: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator({
      ScreenA: {
        screen: ScreenA
      }
    })
  }
})
```

You simply need to move your DrawerNavigator to the top level, and use nested stack navigators like below

```
const stack = DrawerNavigator({
  ScreenA: {
    screen: StackNavigator({
      ScreenA: {
        screen: ScreenA
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: i tried this but then my drawer navigation is not working on clicking my drawer is not opening